# Footer being shown under header navigation

Tags: html, css

Been having issue with the footer in my theme showing under my navigation in the header for some reason (Only happening when the width of the browser is between 1200 - 980). Just isn't seeing what the issue is.

**Screenshot:**
http://goo.gl/qfSNrv

**Live Preview:**
http://goo.gl/uFpRco

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Best Regards,
David

Comment: Just inspecting your website, I'm not sure of the issue; however, you can start by organizing your HTML better. Ex. Your `<header>` is inside your `<div class="wra">` with your main website content, but your `<footer>` is in `<div class="container">` - I would include everything within `<div class="wra">`, and use your `<div class="container">` to hold your `<div class="row">`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a `clear:both` to the css for the footer tag would do the trick.

```
footer {
    border-top: 3px solid #20C8AD;
    height: 80px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    color: #677786;
    background: #34495E;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: @MCSI
    `.wra {
        overflow:hidden;
    }`
causes the dropdown-menu to crop out when you hover over the blog's dropdown-toggle